# Breaking out of the arduino fingerprint enroll loop

Tags: arduino-uno, loop

I am using the Arduino's Adafruit Finger Sensor library, and it has an example to enroll a fingerprint. I want it to enroll one print and exit/break out of the loop because it currently enrolls a user, then goes back to asking for a fingerprint.
Here is the code:

```
#include <Adafruit_Fingerprint.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(2, 3);
Adafruit_Fingerprint finger = Adafruit_Fingerprint(&mySerial);
uint8_t id;
void setup()  
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);  // For Yun/Leo/Micro/Zero/...
  delay(100);
  Serial.println("\n\nAdafruit Fingerprint sensor enrollment");

  // set the data rate for the sensor serial port
  finger.begin(57600);
  
  if (finger.verifyPassword()) {
    Serial.println("Found fingerprint sensor!");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Did not find fingerprint sensor :(");
    while (1) { delay(1); }
  }
}

uint8_t readnumber(void) {
  uint8_t num = 0;
  
  while (num == 0) {
    while (! Serial.available());
    num = Serial.parseInt();
  }
  return num;
}

void loop()                     // run over and over again
{
  Serial.println("Ready to enroll a fingerprint!");
  Serial.println("Please type in the ID # (from 1 to 127) you want to save this finger as...");
  id = readnumber();
  if (id == 0) {// ID #0 not allowed, try again!
     return;
  }
  Serial.print("Enrolling ID #");
  Serial.println(id);
  
  while (!  getFingerprintEnroll() );
}

uint8_t getFingerprintEnroll() {

  int p = -1;
  Serial.print("Waiting for valid finger to enroll as #"); Serial.println(id);
  while (p != FINGERPRINT_OK) {
    p = finger.getImage();
    switch (p) {
    case FINGERPRINT_OK:
      Serial.println("Image taken");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_NOFINGER:
      Serial.println(".");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
      Serial.println("Communication error");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEFAIL:
      Serial.println("Imaging error");
      break;
    default:
      Serial.println("Unknown error");
      break;
    }
  }

  // OK success!

  p = finger.image2Tz(1);
  switch (p) {
    case FINGERPRINT_OK:
      Serial.println("Image converted");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEMESS:
      Serial.println("Image too messy");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
      Serial.println("Communication error");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_FEATUREFAIL:
      Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_INVALIDIMAGE:
      Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
      return p;
    default:
      Serial.println("Unknown error");
      return p;
  }
  
  Serial.println("Remove finger");
  delay(2000);
  p = 0;
  while (p != FINGERPRINT_NOFINGER) {
    p = finger.getImage();
  }
  Serial.print("ID "); Serial.println(id);
  p = -1;
  Serial.println("Place same finger again");
  while (p != FINGERPRINT_OK) {
    p = finger.getImage();
    switch (p) {
    case FINGERPRINT_OK:
      Serial.println("Image taken");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_NOFINGER:
      Serial.print(".");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
      Serial.println("Communication error");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEFAIL:
      Serial.println("Imaging error");
      break;
    default:
      Serial.println("Unknown error");
      break;
    }
  }

  // OK success!

  p = finger.image2Tz(2);
  switch (p) {
    case FINGERPRINT_OK:
      Serial.println("Image converted");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEMESS:
      Serial.println("Image too messy");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
      Serial.println("Communication error");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_FEATUREFAIL:
      Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_INVALIDIMAGE:
      Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
      return p;
    default:
      Serial.println("Unknown error");
      return p;
  }
  
  // OK converted!
  Serial.print("Creating model for #");  Serial.println(id);
  
  p = finger.createModel();
  if (p == FINGERPRINT_OK) {
    Serial.println("Prints matched!");
  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR) {
    Serial.println("Communication error");
    return p;
  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_ENROLLMISMATCH) {
    Serial.println("Fingerprints did not match");
    return p;
  } else {
    Serial.println("Unknown error");
    return p;
  }   
  
  Serial.print("ID "); Serial.println(id);
  p = finger.storeModel(id);
  if (p == FINGERPRINT_OK) {
    Serial.println("Stored!");
  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR) {
    Serial.println("Communication error");
    return p;
  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_BADLOCATION) {
    Serial.println("Could not store in that location");
    return p;
  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_FLASHERR) {
    Serial.println("Error writing to flash");
    return p;
  } else {
    Serial.println("Unknown error");
    return p;
  }   
}
```

Output is that after storing the fingerprint, it requests for finger to enroll, but I want it to exit after storing. Is this possible?

Comment: You are missing a return statement, when the fingerprint was enrolled correctly. Though to what do you want to exit the enrollment loop? Your code does not have anything else in it. When getting out of the while loop, it will just as again for the next ID, because it is the only thing, that you have programmed it for

Comment: I want it to ask for the ID....back at the loop instead of calling the getFingerprintEnroll() method again

Answer (score 1):

Your `getFingerprintEnroll()` function is missing a return statement. Inside the `if (p == FINGERPRINT_OK)` statement, you need to insert

```
return 0;
```

after the Serial print. Only when returning zero, you will exit the while loop inside the `loop()` function.